# How to perform a LEFT JOIN in SQL Server between two SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have two SELECT statements in SQL Server like these:

```
(SELECT [UserID] FROM [User])
(SELECT [TailUser], [Weight] FROM [Edge] WHERE [HeadUser] = 5043)
```

I want to perform a LEFT JOIN between these two SELECT statements on [UserID] attribute and [TailUser] attribute. I want to join existent records in second query with the corresponding records in first query and NULL value for absent records. How can I do this?

Comment: This question should be reopened, as left joining two select statements is as general and specific a task as any; the comment "this question is unlikely to help any future visitors" is false, as it helped me.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT [UserID] FROM [User]) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT [TailUser], [Weight] FROM [Edge] WHERE [HeadUser] = 5043) b
ON a.UserId = b.TailUser
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT [UserID] FROM [User] u LEFT JOIN (
SELECT [TailUser], [Weight] FROM [Edge] WHERE [HeadUser] = 5043) t on t.TailUser=u.USerID
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from user
left join edge
on user.userid = edge.tailuser
and edge.headuser = 5043
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user.userID, edge.TailUser, edge.Weight 
FROM user
LEFT JOIN edge ON edge.HeadUser = User.UserID
WHERE edge.HeadUser=5043
```

OR

```
AND edge.HeadUser=5043
```

instead of a WHERE clause.