# Merging two SQL queries while being able to access elements within each

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two queries:

```
    SELECT applicationid as LastMonthID, month(sold) AS LastMonthSold, SUM(quantity) AS LastMonthTotalSales
FROM(
    SELECT applicationid, sold, quantity
    FROM Sales
    JOIN WebApplication
    ON applicationid = id) AS AllMonthlySales
WHERE month(sold) = month(now())-1
GROUP BY applicationid;


SELECT applicationid ThisMonthID, month(sold) AS ThisMonthSold, SUM(quantity) AS ThisMonthTotalSales
FROM ( 
    SELECT applicationid, sold, quantity
    FROM Sales
    JOIN WebApplication
    ON applicationid = id) As AllMonthlySales
WHERE month(sold) = MONTH(now())
GROUP BY applicationid;
```

These queries produce the following:

1. applicationid
2. the month (number) for which the sale happened
3. The sum of the quantity sold for EACH application

I would like to do the following:

1. Compare last month's quantity, to this month's quantity for EACH application. If there is a 5% DECREASE in the quantity sold, it should give me the applicationid for THAT specific application. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform a LEFT JOIN in SQL Server between two SELECT statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890488/how-to-perform-a-left-join-in-sql-server-between-two-select-statements)

Comment: I think I know but. all the same. which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @strawberry I am using MYSQL

Comment: Then you should edit your question and remove the sql server tag.

Comment: @RC. Not possible. Why is this a _left join_ problem and not a _right join_ problem? Answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one query using conditional aggregates. This will just give you your quantities for this month and last month in two different columns:

```
SELECT  applicationid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.Sold) = MONTH(NOW()) THEN s.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS ThisMonth,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.Sold) = MONTH(NOW()) - 1 THEN s.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS LastMonth
FROM    Sales AS s
        INNER JOIN WebApplication AS w
            ON w.ApplicationID = s.ID
WHERE   MONTH(Sold) INT (MONTH(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()) - 1)
GROUP BY w.ApplicationID;
```

Then you can just limit this to thow where `ThisMonth` is 5% less than `LastMonth` - `(ThisMonth / LastMonth < 0.95)` with the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT  applicationid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.Sold) = MONTH(NOW()) THEN s.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS ThisMonth,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.Sold) = MONTH(NOW()) - 1 THEN s.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS LastMonth
FROM    Sales AS s
        INNER JOIN WebApplication AS w
            ON w.ApplicationID = s.ID
WHERE   MONTH(Sold) INT (MONTH(NOW()), MONTH(NOW()) - 1)
GROUP BY w.ApplicationID
HAVING (ThisMonth / LastMonth) < 0.95;
```

N.B. MySQL Allows you to refer to column aliases in the `HAVING` clause, with other DBMS you will need to repeat the expression:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.Sold) = MONTH(NOW()) THEN s.Quantity ELSE 0 END) / 
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(s.Sold) = MONTH(NOW()) - 1 THEN s.Quantity ELSE 0 END) < 0.95
```

Finally, I would not use `WHERE MONTH(sold) = MONTH(NOW())`, for one thing it will return results from this month in previous years, and secondly, it is not sargable, instead get the first day of this month using:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

and the first day of next month:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

and then you can compare dates between:

```
WHERE sold >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
AND Sold < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

This means any index on `Sold` is now usable.