# SQL join tables based on if else if conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, right-join

New to doing SQL stuff so please excuse me.

I want to create a SQL query that joins a column to table A from table B based on the following match logic:

```
B.Source = ‘SOURCE1’ and A.NameCode= B.Code
```

If the above return NULL then I’d like to match on:

```
B.Source <> ‘SOURCE1’ and A.UEN = B.UEN**
```

Any help on how to structure this?
I currently have a union all select query that can get the values based on the above conditions. Should I be using an If/or/case_when in the join process?

A few questions in which I thought could be helpful and that I've looked at are:

[How to perform a LEFT JOIN in SQL Server between two SELECT statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890488/how-to-perform-a-left-join-in-sql-server-between-two-select-statements)

[Using IS NULL or IS NOT NULL on join conditions - Theory question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630887/using-is-null-or-is-not-null-on-join-conditions-theory-question)

But I was not able to come up with anything :( 
Thank you so much!

Comment: The MySQL optimizer can have problems generating an optimal plan with an `OR` condition. We can try rewriting the query, and comparing performance, EXPLAIN output.  Oftentimes, for the best performance, we end up with two separate queries combined with UNION ALL. That can often be more efficient, with each SELECT taking advantage of the most appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
JOIN B ON (
    (B.Source = 'Source1' AND A.NameCode = B.Code) OR
    (B.Source <> 'Source1' AND A.UEN = B.[UEN**]) --Not sure what the ** is?  Part of the field name?
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great!

Comment: Just add  "AND B.date = '2018-10-17" inside the correct OR clause.